# Swift 4 initWithObject equivalent

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsmutablearray

New to Swift. I have an Objective-C piece of code which looks like this:

```
self.imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{@"name":@"James",@"image":@"1.jpg",@"Address":@"xyz"},
                  @{@"name":@"Doe",@"image":@"2.jpg",@"Address":@"xyz"},nil];
```

How can i use the same `initWithObjects` function with Swift. I have read online that we need to create an `extension` and then use the `zip` function. However from the docs it seems the zip function only takes 2 sequences. My imageArray has dictionary objects consisting of 3 different keys/values.

I tried the following, but not sure how to assign the values to the respective key:

```
  extension Dictionary{

        for (name, address, image) in zip(names, address, images) {
        self[name] = names
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, we'd probably use a native `Array` (designated with the `[` and `]`) rather than a `NSMutableArray` object. The Swift equivalent of your code snippet would be to use a Swift `Array` of `Dictionary` objects:

```
var imageArray: [[String: String]]?
```

And then:

```
imageArray = [["name": "James", "image": "1.jpg", "Address": "xyz"],
              ["name": "Doe",   "image": "2.jpg", "Address": "xyz"]]
```

---

Having said that, you'd probably want to use custom object type:

```
struct PersonImage {
    let name: String
    let image: String
    let address: String
}
```

Then define `imageArray` to be an array of `PersonImage`:

```
var imageArray: [PersonImage]?
```

And then

```
imageArray = [PersonImage(name: "James", image: "1.jpg", address: "xyz"),
              PersonImage(name: "Doe",   image: "2.jpg", address: "xyz")]
```

Comment: Wow. Reading through the solution, it seems remarkably simple now. Should have known this. Will accept the answer. Thanks!!